# Playing with shmat and shm_open

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, shared-memory

I just read the manpages for `shm_open` and `shmat` and was trying out the following example. In a file `test.c` I do,

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  void *retval;
  long shmid = atol(argv[1]);

  retval = shmat(shmid, NULL, SHM_RDONLY);
  printf("%p\n", retval);
}
```

And in a wrapper file I do,

```
int setupshm(char *name) {
  int shmid;
  shmid = shm_open(name, O_CREAT|O_RDWR, 0666);
  return shmid;
}

int main() {
  char **envp = NULL;
  char *argv[3];
  char num[10];

  sprintf(num, "%d", setupshm("whatever"));

  argv[1] = "./test";
  argv[2] = num;
  argv[3] = NULL;

  execve("./test", argv, envp);
}
```

I tried adding in a `strerror(errno)` at test.c and I get `Identifier removed`. What does that mean? What am I doing wrong? Given a shared memory identifier(shmid), shouldn't I be able to access the shared memory from any process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shm_open` belongs to the POSIX shared memory API; `shmat` belongs to the older SysV shared memory API. POSIX shm uses file descriptors. SysV shm uses identifiers that exist in a separate space. They don't work together.

To use SysV shm successfully, you must use `shmget` to get an identifier you can `shmat`.

To use POSIX shm successfully, you must `mmap` the file descriptor you got from `shm_open`.